# How to import data in sql server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have data in a separate file in this format: (screen shot of a text file in notepad)

[image]

How can I import it into a SQL Server database table (existing database)?

Comment: use sql server import /export wizard or use ssis. you may need to clean up the data before processing

Comment: Why don't you create a code for this. i.e. read data from the file and insert it in the database.

Comment: U mean a click event with insert query and storing countries name again its city (both in separate tables)? right? @AkashAmin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try the below Query.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Temp') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #Temp
CREATE TABLE #Temp
    (
        Country Varchar(50),
        City Varchar(50)
    )

BULK INSERT #Temp
FROM 'C:\coci.txt'
WITH
(
FIELDTERMINATOR = '^',
ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)

SELECT REPLACE(Country,'"','') AS Country,REPLACE(City,'"','') AS City FROM #Temp t
```

Comment: can you please tell me, where these columns are saved and how can i include them in my existing database?

Answer (score 1):

Please make use of the below code. Its working fine with SQL Server 2012.

```
DECLARE 
@TableName  VARCHAR(128),
@FileName VARCHAR(100),
@filepath VARCHAR(500),
@Pattern VARCHAR(100),
@Query NVARCHAR(1000)

SET @filepath ='C:'
SET @Pattern ='txt'

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#FileNames') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #FileNames

CREATE TABLE #FileNames
(ID INT IDENTITY,
    FileNames   VARCHAR(200)
)

SET @query ='xp_cmdshell ''dir '+@filepath+'\*.'+@pattern +' /b'''
INSERT  INTO #FileNames EXEC (@Query)
DELETE FROM #FileNames WHERE FileNames is NULL
SET @FileName = (SELECT FileNames from #FileNames WHERE FileNames LIKE '%coci%')

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Temp') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #Temp
CREATE TABLE #Temp
    (
        Country Varchar(100),
        City Varchar(100), 
    )

BEGIN
    SET @Query ='BULK INSERT #Temp FROM '''+  @FilePath+'\'+@FileName+'''WITH (DATAFILETYPE=''char'', FIELDTERMINATOR=''^'', ROWTERMINATOR = ''\n'',FIRSTROW = 1)'
    EXEC (@Query)
    SELECT REPLACE(Country,'"','') AS Country,REPLACE(City,'"','') AS City FROM #Temp t
END
```

SET @filepath variable field to the path where you kept your **txt** file

Comment: where should i place this code. actually i am beginner. please guide me a bit more

Comment: You can run this code in sql server management studio. The only thing you need to do is edit  SET @filepath ='Path where your txt file is placed'

Comment: should i select **new query** area and then place code over there and simply click **execute** after changing @filepath?

Comment: it says: 0 row affected 0 row affected . Do i need to specify any database name or table before i execute it?

Comment: No. So it means the path you specified is not correct. The txt file is not present in that particular path

Comment: file name and path is correct. i think it doesnt work for 2008 version

Comment: Its working fine for SQL server 2008.Can you show me how you set the @filepath variable? Make sure there is only one txt file in that particular path.

Comment: my file name is **coci** with .txt extention and is located in c:

Comment: I had edited the query. Please execute it directly. The file name should be "coci" . It shouldn't be "coci.txt" And the file type should be "Text Document"

Comment: i saved the file in D: , stored in C: , stored in a file in C:\data and changed path for a number of time. but this did not run

Comment: i was not specifying the @filepath correctly. Your another answer for this post helped me. Thnku so mcuh. can i enter the city country names to an existing databsae now?

Comment: Sure. You can just modify your INSERT query. Instead of temporary table use actual table name

Answer (score 0):

You can use BULK INSERT command to [import data from text file into SQL Server database table](http://www.kodyaz.com/t-sql/upload-text-file-to-sql-server-database-table.aspx)

```
BULK INSERT StagingTable FROM 'c:\textfile.txt'
```

You can insert data into a staging table (think as a temporary table) and insert to final destination table after you split your raw data from staging table

You can also use [SQL Server Import & Export wizard to import data](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/sql-server-import-data-sql-server-import-export-data-wizard-ssis-package.aspx) into SQL Server. One you create an SSIS package you can then later use it repetitively.

Comment: this query is not working for sql server 2008 via asp.net framework insert command

Comment: Is it possible that you place the code in a Stored Procedure and execute it

Comment: i did it successfully alhamdullilah. can u please tell me how can i now insert these #temp rows in my any existing database

Answer (score 0):

Please try this bulk insert option.

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp
    (
        Country Varchar(50),
        City Varchar(50)
    )

BULK INSERT tempdb.dbo.#Temp
FROM 'C:\data\test.txt'
WITH
(
FIELDTERMINATOR = '^',
ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)
```

Comment: Database name 'tempdb' ignored, referencing object in tempdb.
Msg 2714, Level 16, State 6, Line 1
There is already an object named '#Temp' in the database.

Comment: i am getting this error when i **Execute* this query

Comment: Yes please drop and recreate the #temp table